# What's this syntax called? SomeMoneyFormat f = "€ 5,00";

Tags: c#

I have seen some form of this some time ago, but I cannot recall what it was called, and therefore have no clue on how to implement something like this:

```
SomeMoneyFormat f = "€ 5,00";
```

Which calls some overload function that can parse the string into a `SomeMoneyFormat` object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you do not specify that it should be cast it is an `implicit cast`

```
   public static implicit operator SomeMoneyFormat(string d) 
   {
      return new SomeMoneyFormat(d);
   }
```

Then `€ 5,00` is passed as the string `d`

more about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx

Also, I can add that this should only be done when there is no risk of losing data. For example converting a `double` to an `int` will lose some precision, so it is an `explicit cast`. Otherwise it would be easy to cast by accident and lose data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an [implicit type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28VS.71%29.aspx) to me.